# Get all include files of a cpp file considering preprocessor defines (fast)

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I need a tool (command line, script or source code) that extracts all inlcude files that are included by a source file (recursive) with given preprocessor defines and include paths. I want to know the ones that could be found and the one that doesn't. The include files that could be found shall be recursivly parsed.

I know about the

```
    gcc -M /-MM       
    cl /P
```

solution, but this does not work for me. The preprocessor stops as soon as it could not open a file. But at this time I don't have the correct path for that files and just want the preprocessor to skip that file and to tell me that it could not include that file

Also the **cinclude2dot.pl** from [here](http://flourish.org/cinclude2dot/) is not useful, because it seems not to consider given preprocessor defines.

Very useful is the **include file hierarchy finder** from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3478/Include-File-Hierarchy-Viewer). It considers the preprocessor flags and shows me all include files. Even the includes that couldn't be opened. But it is written in MFC and I would have to reimplement this for the gcc what is not such simple because a lot of WinAPI stuff is used even inside the parser.

Thus, maybe some one knows another solution.

an simple example:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

#include <SharedClass.h>
#include "MyClass.h"

#ifdef FOO
    #include <OptClass.h>
#endif

int main() {}
```

Right now I start the include extraction like (simplified):

```
.getAllIncludes main.cpp -I includepath1;includepath2 -PD FOO
```

and obtain:

- cannot open  //-> I don't care right now, it's a default header
- cannot open   // -> here I can extract the info that I need boost
- SharedClass.h
- SharedDependenyClass.h //a header that is included by SharedClass...
- MyClass.h
- TestClass.h //a header that is included by the MyClass header...
- TestClass2.h //a header that is included by the TestClass header...
- OptClass.h

and for

```
.getAllIncludes main.cpp -I includepath1;includepath2
```

I'll obtain:

- cannot open  //-> I don't care right now, it's a default header
- cannot open   // -> here I can extract the info that I need boost
- SharedClass.h
- SharedDependenyClass.h //a header that is included by SharedClass...
- MyClass.h
- TestClass.h //a header that is included by the MyClass header...
- TestClass2.h //a header that is included by the TestClass header...

I know that the deafault header may also define some values. But in my case I don't need that information, because the project source code doesn't depend on any of that defines. If thus, I feed my tool with this preprocessor define...

In the end the tool works quite well. It runs recursivly over ALL necessary files and in the end I have all needed files for the project. Of course there are some small restrictions I don't want to name then all (e.g. every header of an source file name has the same name, ... ).

Comment: If the last tool does what you want why can't you use it?

Comment: it's written in MFC and has some not std conform issues...

Comment: _'but this means the code gets compiled -> to slow'_ Who told you such rubbish??

Comment: the MFC code cannot be compiled with the gcc. I need a cross platzform  solution. as you can see the gcc/cl preprocessor does not help me out, because they ry to parse all included files and will stop if they do not find them. But my tool is for gathering all necessary files and 3rdParty tools. Right know I wrote a tool by myself that works fine just by 'do main.cpp' -> all nexessary files (header, cpp, 3rdparty libs). But I want to accelerate the part that extracts the include files. PLATTFORM INDEPENDEND -> ergo: I hoped for a solution without reimplemting the MFC solution

Answer (score 2):

Using `gcc -M <source_file>`, the code is not compiled, it is only processed by the precompiler. And, any solution you may find needs to process the source using the precompiler, to be correct. Imagine that the source, somewhere, has the following snipset:

```
#ifdef USE_BOOST_SUPERLIB
#  include <boost/superlib.hpp>
#endif
```

then without preprocessing you cannot know if `<boost/superlib.hpp>` is included.

Comment: it's not compiled, but it stops if a header cannot be found. In my case I'm only intrested in the not std-inlcude headers and 3rdParty headers. the found project headers shall also parsed. all others should be marked as not found. right know I filter all files in respect to the preprocessor defines and use boost wave to figure out what files I need. but I'm looking for a more performant way to solve this probleme. the waver lexer throws exceptions for not found files, but does not stop.

Comment: @muffmolch You are right. For that usage, `-M` does not what you want. I suggest you edit your question.